# SSIS Package failing because "script task is failing because the script is not precompiled"

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I developed a pretty straight forward SSIS package (in VS2005 w/ .Net Framework V 2.0.50727 SP2) that gets a list of users to email, starts a for-each loop container and then executes a script task to retrieve user specific data and email it out to the user.  When I run it on my dev box everything works great and runs as it should.  However when I deploy the package to our production server running (Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64)  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2) ) the task fails.

The original error message is:

> Executed as user: xxxxx. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 9.00.5000.00 for 64-bit   Code: 0x00000009 Source: PackageName     Description: The task cannot execute in 64-bit environment because the script is not pre-compiled. Please turn on the option to pre-compile the script in the task editor.  End Error ... Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

After researching that extensively the interwebs suggested that I try:

1. running the package in 32bit by changing the execution property in the SQL job and by changing my RunIn64BitMode property from true to false

   - which fails because " Option "/X86" is not valid."
2. install the [Microsoft Hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931593)

   - which doesn't apply since I am already running on SP2

So after more research I find that I need to turn on "Please turn on the option to pre-compile the script in the task editor." SOURCE: ssis-dtsx DOT blogspot DOT com/2010/03/cannot-execute-in-64-bit-environment.html
Which entails:

- Make sure that each script task has PreCompile = True
- Open Script Task Editor, switch to Script tab and make sure that
  PrecompileScriptIntoBinaryCode = True
- Click on Design Script to open code editor (Visual Studio for Applications) and then choose it using File > Close and Return (VSA will recompile and store binary code in the package).
- Build Project and copy to target location

However when I execute the package I immediately get the error:

> Executed as user: xxxx. ...0.5000.00 for 64-bit Code: 0x00000008     Source: PackageName Description: The task is configured to pre-compile the script, but binary code is not found. Please visit the IDE in Script Task Editor by clicking Design Script button to cause binary code to be generated.  End Error   Code: 0x00000008     Source: GET PO infor and Email      Description: Script could not be recompiled or run: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID...

So my final step was to turn DelayValidation property from False to True in the SSIS pkg, go into the design script to cause it to be rebuilt, then redeploy, and rerun and I still get the same error.

On searching the error I am directed to [Microsoft HOT FIX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/932556) which suggested that I download another hotfix.

I have not yet downloaded the hotfix, and would prefer not to if I can avoid it (our OPs team doesnt like running hotfixes mid day on production servers).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the package, open the script component, then within Visual Studio (while looking at the code) click on BUILD. This will compile the package, if there are no issues preventing it from compiling. Then SAVE, go back and ensure that you click on "OKAY" and not "cancel", if you click on cancel then the whole thing reverts back.