# Error when adding web service in Script Task in SSIS?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

i have this task to send a RS report (event driven) in SSIS. I have this script task that extracts the report and another script task to send the email.

In my script task I'm able to add the web reference, reference it in the code, build successfully and save it.
  **http://{YourReportServerURL}/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx**

BUT when I exit the script task editor I get a script error saying **"Script contained in the package have compilation errors. Do you want to save changes?"**

A red cross appears on it and it says **"The binary code for the script is not found.".** I set the **DelayValidation** to true to remove this red cross.

When i execute the package, it fails because of the **The binary code for the script is not found** error

By the way these are my references:
http://www.travisgan.com/2013/09/ssrs-data-drive-subscriptions-part-3.html

http://www.macaalay.com/2014/04/02/how-to-create-data-driven-report-subscriptions-in-sql-server-standard-version/

Im using VS 2010. how can I solve this problem? I need your help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to build the script while you are in VSTA Editor. I have encountered cases when VS editor was not doing full parse at edit time, building helped to reveal errors.

Comment: Yes, i build the script while in the editor

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [SSIS Package failing because “script task is failing because the script is not precompiled”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007252/ssis-package-failing-because-script-task-is-failing-because-the-script-is-not-p). Your problem looks similar to the described in that issue.
Basically, you need to make sure that VSTA project code is set to MSIL, build the project and save it. After that - close VSTA editor, and click Ok on the Script task.